# Load a google map with coordinates that is obtained from ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a html page.Initially the data of markers and map and points are coming from controller and below is the corresponding view where in the div 'map' the map is displayed

```
<script>
  function getcoordinates(){
  //to get coordinates using ajax jquery(latitude,longitude)
 }
</script>
    <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
    <input type="text" id="myPlaceTextBox"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="text_id" placeholder="Search id"/>
    <input type='button' name='search_id' value='Search' onClick='getcoordinates()'/>
    <div id='map' style="width:100%; height:100%;"><?php echo $map['html']; ?></div>
```

the div 'map' is already being used to show the map when the page loads.There is also a search with onClick that calls the getcoordinates() function and get the coordinates.I need to reload the map with the new coordinates in the same div 'map'.

I have written the below function which is called from ajax success block but map doesnt seem to load in that div map.

```
function initialize(lat,lng) {
   var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng), //assign Seprately
    zoom: 8,
    scrollwheel: false
};
document.getElementById('map').style.display="block";
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png'
});
alert("loading completed");
}
```

Comment: Are you want to reload the whole map? If I understand correctly, a map is already drawn? I would think it makes more sense to add the marker to the existing map. Also, is the callback called at all?

Comment: actually the markers are drawn by getting the data from the codeigniter controller.Now in the view the markers are showing.Now I have given a search field above.Once the id is searched in the textbox it retrieves the coordinates corresponding to that id from database(this coordinate obtained is among one of the previous markers) and it needs to be displayed in the map zoomed.The searching takes place by calling  the jquery ajax getcoordinates() function mentioned above.The map which is already drawn is using codeigniter map library, but after getting coordinates loading javascript map API.

Comment: Your code is initializing an entirely new map. If you want to show the marker that has been retrieved by your search you'll be better of zooming/panning the map to its position and highlight it in some way.

Comment: your function `getcoordinates` does nothing - what did you expect, some Jimmy Speckerman code?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, its a jquery ajax func that is already fetching latitude longitude from database.But from the success block of jquery ajax I am not able to populate the map in the div 'map' which is already having a map populated  by the google map codeigniter API.Actually the thing is I want to populate a map in the div 'map' by javascript Google Map API which is prepopulated by a map in the same div by the codeigniter Google map API.If you have any difficulties to understand please ask me again.I will try to explain you.